# Read JSCON file with PHP

Tags: java, php, arrays

I'm trying to read a JSON with a php array. The JSON file is using a format that I am not familiar with and I don't know how to write my PHP array so it could read the file.

JSON file in question can be found here: 
http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/ANA/iphone/clubroster.json

The format is giving me hard time because 1) it is starting with a time stamp that my array cannot read and 2) the file is separated between the value position, means that I have a closing statement  ' }] ' before the end of the file - seems like they separated category

My PHP array that work with more standard array :

```
function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" + 
        arr[i].position +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].weight +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].height +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
out += "</table>"
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
```

}

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called JSON, not JSCON. The code you posted is JavaScript, not PHP.

Here is an example of how you could read the JSON you provided with PHP:

```
<?php
    $result = file_get_contents("http://nhlwc.cdnak.neulion.com/fs1/nhl/league/teamroster/ANA/iphone/clubroster.json");
    $json = json_decode($result);
    foreach ($json->goalie as $player) {
        echo $player->name . '</br>';
    }
?>
```

This will print each goalie's name.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need  **JavaScript**(not php) to read this json file?
in JavaScript try

> arr  = val('(' + response + ')')

and in php try

> arr  = json_decode(response)